# mod_rewrite multiple question marks

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Occasionally the marketing department would send out a mailer that contains links with multiple question marks in them.

```
http://www.acme.com/site-page.jsp?content=mainpage?utm_campaign=somecampaign&utm_source=email
```

This results in the application server interpreting the `mainpage?utm_campaign` as the parameter instead of just `mainpage`. Is there a way to intercept these erroneous urls in Apache and replace the second `?` with an `&`.

Comment: Are you able to fire the marketing team?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?)\?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^site-page\.jsp$ /site-page.jsp?%1&%2 [R=302,L]
```

This code will redirect

```
/site-page.jsp?content=mainpage?utm_campaign=somecampaign&utm_source=email
```

to

```
/site-page.jsp?content=mainpage&utm_campaign=somecampaign&utm_source=email
```

Now you have those params:

- `content` = `mainpage`
- `utm_campaign` = `somecampaign`
- `utm_source` = `email`

Note: feel free to change `302` (temporary) redirect to a 301 (permanent) redirect

---

EDIT

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?)\?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&%2 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: What if `site-page.jsp` is not consistent?

Comment: Would you want to redirect it to an existing page ? What would you want to do instead ?

Comment: Being a bit vague, been a long week and it is just Monday. The target URL will always be the same as the original URL but I don't want to write a rule for say site-page1.jsp and site-page2.jsp. So while the `QUERY_STRING` needs to be cleaned up, the requested target page will remain the same. Hopefully that makes sense now? I think I want the `$PATH_INFO` to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue that more than one additional question mark can appear in my query strings. At first I began to write multiple rules for multiple use cases but happend to find the `NE|No Escape` flag.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\?(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1&%2 [NE,R=302,L]
```

will do the trick.

This way the question marks will be removed recursively. That increases the number of request to the number of additional question marks but decreases the number of rules to one.

I also changed the regex a bit. That way additional question marks at the beginning and at the end of the query string will also be replaced. Not a common case, but if we were only facing common cases, we wouldn't need those rules at all ;-)